# How pool.map() allocates the work internally?

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I am quite new to `multiprocessing` library and have question with regards to its `Pool` module when used with `map()`. Suppose I have 4 worker threads and 6 tasks to be completed. What I do is (using `multiprocessing.dummy` because I want to spawn threads and not processes)

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def print_it(num):
    print num

def multi_threaded():
    tasks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    r = pool.map(print_it, tasks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

multi_threaded()
```

I want to understand how Pool.map() handles the tasks? Three options :

1. Does it spawn 4 threads first, get the first 4 tasks complete and let the threads die. Then spawns 2 new threads for the remaining tasks?
2. Does it spawn 4 threads, assign 4 tasks to them, as soon as some thread completes its task, assign new task to the same thread.
3. Some other way.

This insight would be helpful as it will help me think of using `Pool.map()` more effectively in prod.

Comment: Practically all pools I know, does (2). But I don't know this specific library, and typically I have mainly disappointing experiences with python + multithread things. I think some limitedly smart solution is quite possible. Good luck for a detailed answer.

Comment: You could do a test to see what happens by making the `print_it` function also `sleep`. And doing this test in Python 3.6 it looks like new tasks start as soon as there is a spare thread to handle it.

Comment: Why not [read the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5e02c7826f9797fb3add79b608ef51f7a62b3e5a/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L146) and see for yourself? The `ThreadPool` class is a subclass of the normal `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, which overrides a few things (you can see it's definition at the bottom of the file if you want to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you define your pool.

As you do it in your example, your (2) happens. Your threads or processes depending on Pool get launched as soon as you initialise your Pool (happens in `Pool__init__()` - no need to submit tasks for this to happen) and they sit there waiting for tasks. When a task arrives and is executed, threads or processes do not exit, they just go back to waiting state waiting for more work to come.

You can define it work differently, though. You can add `maxtasksperchild` parameter to your pool. As soon as a worker has completed this amount of tasks, it exits, and a new worker is immediately launched (no need to give it a task first, it gets launched as soon as a worker exits). This is managed in Pool class `Pool._maintain_pool()` and `Pool._repopulate_pool()` functions.

If you want your workers to launch at start and run indefinitely, do what you do now and this is what happens. If you want your workers to launch at start but exit and renew themselves after a number of tasks (even one if necessary), use `maxtasksperchild`. If you do not want to launch processes or threads before there is a need for them, do not use Pool. Launch threads or processes when you need them and manage them yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer. Thanks you.